# cascade option in gulp-autoprefixer

Tags: css, gulp, gulp-sass, gulp-autoprefixer

While adding the autoprfixing task from the gulp-autoprefixer plugin I noticed the

```
autoprefixer({ cascade: false })
```

option. And this option was not clear for me what it is doing.

In the documentation I read that:

> cascade (boolean): should Autoprefixer use Visual Cascade, if CSS is uncompressed. Default: true

So I compiled my SASS to the CSS with the cascade: false and with cascade true and I got the same result in both cases:
My SASS:

```
body
display: flex
p
    display: flex
```

Compiled to the CSS with the `autoprefixer({ cascade: false })`:

```
body {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex; }
body p {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex; }
```

Compiled to the CSS with the `autoprefixer({ cascade: true })`:

```
body {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex; }
body p {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex; }
```

So my final question is - **What the autoprefixer's cascade: false/true option is responsible for?**

Thank you very much for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was actually also curious about this and noticed the following when `cascade: true` (which is the default):

given this:

```
body {
    background: black;
  display: flex;
    flex-direction:  row-reverse; }
```

autoprefixer outputs:

```
body {
  background: black;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: reverse;
      -ms-flex-direction: row-reverse;
          flex-direction: row-reverse; }
```

notice the indentations in the lines following `-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;`

however, if `cascade: false`:

```
body {
  background: black;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: reverse;
  -ms-flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex-direction: row-reverse; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and this is what I found:

*'To make your CSS look pretty, autoprefixer can cascade the prefixes—adding whitespace to make the prefixes line up (although, if you’re using the minification gulp plugin, it won’t make any difference in the end)'*

-> https://www.futurehosting.com/blog/use-autoprefixer-to-speed-up-site-development/